# jsoup doesn't work in my android application, always get error with get()

Tags: android, html, eclipse, jsoup

Here's part of my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lyrics_display);
    setupActionBar();

    TextView ArtistName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.aname);
    TextView SongName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sname);

     // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    String message2 = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE2);

    // Create the text view
    ArtistName.setTextSize(12);
    ArtistName.setText(message);
    SongName.setTextSize(12);
    SongName.setText(message2);
    getLyrics(message , message2);
}

@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
public void getLyrics(String message , String message2) {

    final TextView LyricsContent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lyricscontent);
    Document doc = null;
    String  url = "http://api.chartlyrics.com/apiv1.asmx/SearchLyricDirect?artist="+message.toLowerCase()+"&song="+message2.toLowerCase();
    LyricsContent.setText(url);
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }           
}
```

It always stops after i input (String message , String message2). 
I'm with it already: android.permission.INTERNET android.persmission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE/>

And when I delete the part of jsoup, it works. so where goes wrong?

Comment: Post the stack trace. Also seems you're doing network operations on the main Thread, resulting in a `NetworkOnMainThreadException.` Don't do that.

Comment: -1 for A/ not posting stacktrace. B/ not defining "error" C/ not having googled the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Hello I had this also in my application.

The solution is fairly simple:

All Jsoup actions have to be done in an Asyntask or Thread

I personally use an Asynctask like this:

have a String lyrics on top of the code before activity

```
    private class LoadLyric extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Here you can do any UI operations like textview.setText("test");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        lyrics = doc.text(); // or atleast do something like doc.getElementsByTag("Lyric"); in your case

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you dont have to make any connection in the Activity, and you call getLyrics().

```
@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
public void getLyrics(String message , String message2) {
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        final TextView LyricsContent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lyricscontent);
        Document doc = null;
        String  url = "http://api.chartlyrics.com/apiv1.asmx/SearchLyricDirect?artist="+message.toLowerCase()+"&song="+message2.toLowerCase();
        LyricsContent.setText(url);
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }           
}
}).start();
}
```